# Google Maps display in Custom Object - returns blank

Tags: custom-object, map

Disclaimer: I am very new to VF. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. (:

I am trying to insert a google map location for the address in my custom object.  It returns a blank field when I enter this code.

The code below is a modified version of the code listed here:
http://phollaio.tumblr.com/post/22058038379/inline-google-maps-using-visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="SVMXC__Service_Order__c">

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    mapTypeControl: false
  }

  var map;
  var marker;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.SVMXC__Street__c}, " + "{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.SVMXC__City__c}, " + "{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.SVMXC__Zip__c}, ";

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.SVMXC__Street__c}, " + "{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.SVMXC__City__c}, " + "{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.SVMXC__Zip__c},"
  });

  geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

        //create map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        //center map
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        //create marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: "{!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.Insured__c}"
        });

        //add listeners
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); 
        });

      }

    } else {
      $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
      $('#map').html("Oops! {!SVMXC__Service_Order__c.Insured__c}'s address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
      resizeIframe();
    }
  });

  function resizeIframe() {
    var me = window.name;
    if (me) {
      var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
      if (iframes && iframes.length == 1) {
        height = document.body.offsetHeight;
        iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
      }
    }
  }

});
</script>

<style>
#map {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:normal !important;
  height:250px;
  background:transparent;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div> 
</body> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors on the page?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you are using `https` when you load some ressources in your page (you can replace `http://maps...` by `//maps....` to let the browser decide which protocol to use).

Second, include scripts this way:

`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js")}`